# Flutter material button with unwanted padding/additional width

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't figure out what's giving this button extra width/padding. The image used is cropped so has no spacing to the left or right and you can see in the attached screenshot from the dev tools that it doesn't occupy the width. Somehow the button has extra width but I don't know where it's coming from.

I have another identical button next to it and with the added space it's causing overflow.

[image]

[image]

Changing the image size with the width parameter doesn't affect the amount of space the material button takes up either. It seems to be a fixed size.

This is the whole code:

```
Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          MaterialButton(
            child: Image.asset("images/male.png", width: 33)
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

I also tried other buttons like `FlatButton` and `RaisedButton` but they are the same with this additional width/padding. I also tried setting `padding` with on the button to `EdgeInsets.all(0)` but that doesn't change anything either.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Inconsistent column padding on Buttons between Android and Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76384490/flutter-inconsistent-column-padding-on-buttons-between-android-and-windows)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The extra space is from the minWidth default value which is taken from  the current `ButtonTheme` (you can see that from the `MaterialButton` source code). You can remove the extra space by adding `minWidth` to 0 and `padding` to 0 to your `MaterialButton` widget. Something like this:

```
Scaffold(
  body: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      MaterialButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        minWidth: 0,
        child: Image.asset("images/male.png", width: 33),
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Aha that's it! Thankyou, that is exactly what it is. I tried padding to zero but it has a minWidth value as well as you say.

Comment: add property `height: 0` to remove default `minHeight`.

Comment: A more official way is to use EdgeInsets.zero

Answer (score 0):

```
MaterialButton(
            minWidth: 0,
            materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -2):

Use a container, where you can specify the width

```
Scaffold(
      body: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
new Container(
width: 33,
child : MaterialButton(
            child: Image.asset("images/male.png")
  ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: But why does it have that extra width? Why do I have to fix it with an outside container?

Comment: The materialButton Class will expand itself to fit the child when required.

Comment: Yeah but that's my point, it's NOT expanding. Check the screenshots above, the image inside is very small and even changing the image size does not change according to the child whatsoever. It's just fixed with unnecessary padding for no reason.

Comment: It seems you're completely wrong, it has a `minWidth` setting as explained in the other answer.