# Flutter: Inconsistent column padding on Buttons between Android and Windows

Tags: android, windows, flutter

I have created a simple material app in flutter with:

`flutter create --platforms=android,windows columntest`

When I run the program on Android and Windows, I get some kind of padding between the ElevatedButtons on Android, but not on Windows. Do you know where this comes from and how I can make the design consistent?

The behavior seems to occur only with buttons (TextButton, OutlinedButton, ElevatedButton).
I have also tested this with container (with border), there it does not occur.

Here the code from the small app:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(child: const Text("Foobar1"), onPressed: () {}),
              ElevatedButton(child: const Text("Foobar2"), onPressed: () {}),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot at runtime:
[image: flutter_column_button_padding_problem]

Here my flutter version:

```
$ flutter --version
Flutter 3.10.0 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 84a1e904f4 (3 weeks ago) • 2023-05-09 07:41:44 -0700
Engine • revision d44b5a94c9
Tools • Dart 3.0.0 • DevTools 2.23.1
```

My Android Emulator is an: Pixel_3a_API_33_x86_64
But the behaviour also occurs on my physical Pixel 6 (with android UpsideDownCake)

I look forward to your responses.

best regards
Michael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this implementation is done by flutter.

This is behaviour is because of the ThemeData.materialTapTargetSize parameter for the `MaterialApp`.
This feature decides what should be touchable dimensions of Material Button, in your case `ElevatedButton`.

You have 2 potential solutions

1. Change padding from ElevatedButton like below

```
    ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: const ButtonStyle(padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(EdgeInsets.zero)),
              child: const Icon(Icons.abc),
            ),
```

2. Change value from material app

```
    MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        materialTapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap),
      home: CupertinoPickerExample(),
    )
```

Reference :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/67580951

Comment: Hey, thanks. Number 2 is the correct solution I was looking for.